# Javascript / jquery not working in other files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this ajax email subscription function which works great in a stand alone single html file with just one form and one email input field  but when I try to embed it in homapage (having other form elements and scripts) of other websites it doesn't work beyond "Please Wait..." message.

I believe it has something to do with referencing for which I have very poor concepts can you please tell how can I fix it 
Thankyou

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    rclear = $('#s-clear');
    rclear.hide();
    //rclear.hide();
    $('#newsletter-signup').submit(function(){
        //check the form is not currently submitting
        if($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting'){
            //setup variables
            var form = $(this),
                formData = form.serialize(),
                formUrl = form.attr('action'),
                formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
                responseMsg = $('#signup-response');
            //add status data to form
            form.data('formstatus','submitting');
            //show response message - waiting
            rclear.hide();
            responseMsg.hide()
                       .addClass('response-waiting')
                       .text('Please Wait...')
                       .fadeIn(200);
            //send data to server for validation
            $.ajax({
                url: formUrl,
                type: formMethod,
                data: formData,
                success:function(data){
                    //setup variables
                    var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                        klass = '';
                    //response conditional
                    switch(responseData.status){
                        case 'error':
                            klass = 'response-error';
                        break;
                        case 'success':
                            klass = 'response-success';
                        break;  
                    }
                    //show reponse message
                    responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                               .addClass(klass)
                               .text(responseData.message)
                               .fadeIn(200,function(){
                                   //set timeout to hide response message
                                   setTimeout(function(){
                                       responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                           $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                           form.data('formstatus','idle');
                                           rclear.show();
                                       });
                                   },3000)
                                });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        //prevent form from submitting
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div style="background: #9FCBFF;width: 185px;height: 105px" >
<form id="newsletter-signup" action="?action=signup" method="post">
<div>
    <fieldset>
    <p id="signup-response"></p>
        <p id="s-clear"> </p>
       <div> <input type="text" name="email" id="signup-email" /></div>
        <div><input type="submit" id="signup-button" value="Subscribe" /></div>

    </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is jquery conflict. If you are using different javascript plugins(with $ as variable or function name) in the home page that are not used in the stand alone page, there is chances for jquery conflicts.
Try:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the console for error messages? Also, check the top right corner of the address box to make sure that the page has not blocked the script.

Comment: Well other scripts are running fine on that page I have not checked console errors since I'm just a newbie, OK thanks for hint let me see ......